# Текст в toolbar android

Tags: android, текст

Есть одинаковые окна, но с разной ориентацией. В вертикальной ориентации название окна большое, а в горизонтальной маленькое. Как делать так, чтобы в горизонтальное ориентации текст был больше?

[image: t]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему можно решить созданием своего стиля. Вот ваш тулбар:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

и вот собственно стиль для него:

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Если же у вас нету такого вью элемента, то можно напрямую в активности применять стиль для этого:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.your_style);
```

Comment: После этого у меня весь текст меняет размер, но не заголовок

Comment: что из этого вы пробовали и как именно?

Comment: Добавил  в style информация о размере(как по умолчанию + размер), а потом пытался сделать его в activity, программа ошибок не показывала, но на устройстве приложения аварийно завершало работу

Comment: @Unknown, если приложение завершает работу, то значит ошибка есть, подключите телефон к пк и получите ошибку, которую можете тут показать

Comment: Т.е надо в activity сверху написать <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />                                                             
 а в style написать <style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>. так?

Comment: это один из вариантов добавления виджета тулбара в активность

Comment: а через activity Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.your_style); в yout_style писать свой стиль с указание размера?

Comment: да, здесь нужно использовать созданный вами стиль, либо возьмите дефолтный тулбар, а не добавляйте новый, но при этом у вас должна быть тема с поддержкой тулбара

Comment: <style name="my_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"> Может ли ошибка в parent

Comment: Вы ошибку получить смогли? Так сложно сказать где проблема

Comment: https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipNTcZeAhR2IvSTcnzU_4z-s8QlWwaq9jAytxvnx https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipMY226vmcDZmPW2WhNq8mO954SHNovD7rrn-KFA